# ( Signup Form ) Ajax seems to not be working, only showing up my echo, not my message to look in your email

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms

> First you click on the button, then it tells you to look in the terms,
>   so you do. Then it officially makes your account. Although, once you
>   click on the button it should've redirected you to the message header.
>   Instead it shows the echo, it doesn't direct you to the message. It
>   stays where it is, and it just says signup_success.
>
> My ajax seems fine.

```
    function ajaxObj( meth, url ) {
    var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
    x.open( meth, url, true );
    x.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    return x;
}
function ajaxReturn(x){
    if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
        return true;
    }
}
```

> Not sure if its this code, or the ajax thats wrong.

```
function restrict(elem){
    var tf = _(elem);
    var rx = new RegExp;
    if(elem == "email"){
        rx = /[' "]/gi;
    } else if(elem == "username"){
        rx = /[^a-z0-9]/gi;
    }
    tf.value = tf.value.replace(rx, "");
}
function emptyElement(x){
    _(x).innerHTML = "";
}
function checkusername(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    if(u != ""){
        _("unamestatus").innerHTML = 'checking ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                _("unamestatus").innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
            }
        }
        ajax.send("usernamecheck="+u);
    }
}
function signup(){
    var u = _("username").value;
    var e = _("email").value;
    var p1 = _("pass1").value;
    var p2 = _("pass2").value;
    var c = _("country").value;
    var g = _("gender").value;
    var status = _("status");
    if(u == "" || e == "" || p1 == "" || p2 == "" || c == "" || g == ""){
        status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
    } else if(p1 != p2){
        status.innerHTML = "Your password fields do not match";
    } else if( _("terms").style.display == "none"){
        status.innerHTML = "Please view the terms of use";
    } else {
        _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
        status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
        var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
                if(ajax.responseText.indexOf("signup_success")){
                    status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                    _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
                } else {
                    window.scrollTo(0,0);
                    _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
                }
            }
        }
        ajax.send("u="+u+"&e="+e+"&p="+p1+"&c="+c+"&g="+g);
    }
}
function openTerms(){
    _("terms").style.display = "block";
    emptyElement("status");
}
/* function addEvents(){
    _("elemID").addEventListener("click", func, false);
}
window.onload = addEvents; */
```

> I've been working on it a while now, everything was going smooth, then BAMB the button didn't work. Then I fixed it, and now it just won't direct to the message.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522643/ajax-php-conditional-logic-not-evaluating-correctly
So I happen to magically go to this awesome page, and found someone who knows. If you're looking for the same go there or look below and that's all you have to do.


"Try removing unnecessary whitespace from your script or trim the responseText:"

if(ajax.responseText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, "") == "signup_success") ...